# Draw floorpan to extrude?

Tags: extrude

[image]I'm new to Blender, coming from an arch vis background. Is there a way to draw a series of walls using some sort of spline / path tool, with a degree of accuracy, and then extrude to create walls?

All the tutorials I've watched simply show people rescaling planes and the like - I haven't come across a way to accurately input wall edges?

Thanks,

Derek

Comment: What you could do is draw your walls on a plane with single edges, then bevel them to give thickness, and extrude up, I'm not sure it's very interesting compared to playing with some parallelepipeds, but maybe give more details?

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how to post an image showing what I'm after, but say I imported a CAD floorpan of a building. Would I be able to somehow have this as reference, and then trace out the walls to create extrudable elements? All the tutorials I've watched just seem to suggest we build stuff up by eye, using rectangles. Often buildings aren't that simple, and we need some accuracy. I can't see any sort of 'spline' tool in the Create tab - Path and Bezier Curve don't seem to achieve it, from what I can see...

Comment: you can extrude curves and solidify them to give thickness but I'm not sure it's more convenient than rectangle meshes, and anyway a curve can't have several branches so it won't simplify the work

Comment: So is there simply no way of drawing a 2D polygon from scratch in Blender? Sounds like I have to edit a plane, or else import one?

Comment: please show some pictures, it will help to have a real case...

Comment: Can't see any options for how to upload an image. To put it simply, I just want to be able to quickly draw a polygon from scratch. I'm amazed there doesn't seem to be a simple 'polygon' or 'spline' tool where you can click a series of points in 2D space and it closes the shape and fills it with a face - it's one of the most basic tools in a lot of other packages!

Comment: you can, but you need to give a precise example, for example if you press shift A > Circle, you can choose how many vertices your circle is made of, so you can create an hexagon or whatever, but your question is too vague. You can edit your question and use the image button to upload any image.

Comment: so for the kind of plan you've displayed, put it as a background image, create a plane, then scale it, create edge loops, extrude, etc...

Comment: Thanks. And is there a way to do this accurately? Say I wanted to add the next wall vertex 3.7m from the corner? Or my tangent wall that I want to extrude needs to be exactly 300mm thick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Just start from a single vertex (make a plane and delete 3 out of 4 vertices) and extrude it like so. You can make sure your vertices are aligned by turning snapping to grid ON, or selecting multiple vertices that need to be aligned and scaling them to 0 on the relevant axis.

Once you finish your shape, select all vertices and press F to create a face, then use the Solidify modifier or extrude the face.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think so - thank you! I assume there's a way I can extrude those vertices by a set distance?

Comment: Yes, press E, then press the key for the axis (X, Y or Z), then type the distance (you can type .5 for a 50cm extrusion)

Comment: Perfect, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For the kind of plan you've uploaded, put it as a background image, create a plane, then scale it, create edge loops, extrude, etc... Once you've finished, extrude up.

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I think the method below (starting with a single vertex) is probably closer to what I'm used to doing.